# Adding CSS around taxonomy terms in node field

Tags: 7, entities, taxonomy-terms

In my node, I have a taxonomy field that displays one or more taxonomy terms (as plain text using DS).  I want to wrap a CSS class around the term, depending on the term value.

Where is the best place to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this in preprocess_taxonomy_term(), and just added to classes_array.